# Most efficient way to access Pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Python that I want to trace through in a very specific way and I'm very new to using Pandas so I need some advice on how best to do this. This dataframe has information on many, many video games released over the course of history. Each row is an entry for a particular video game and each column contains info such as game names, release years, sales numbers, and console platforms (the same game appears multiple times if released on multiple platforms).

I want to do some calculations on sales figures based on release consoles over particular dates. The most obvious way of doing this is, of course, manually looping over every row in the dataframe checking to see if entries match my particular requirements for a calculation.

This is how I plan to do my traversals:

```
for s in frame.iterrows():
    if s[1][1] == "Wii":
        print (s[1][1]) ##As a test, I can print out the names of Wii games
```

My question is if this is the "correct" or most efficient way to do this, which I assume it's not. Pandas seems to have a TON of useful methods for dataframes and I would like to know if it contains a more efficient method for only looking up data with certain prerequisites.

Comment: In pandas, you almost never have to use a for loop, though you may need to provide a sample of your data frame and what do you need to achieve to get further help

Comment: Read up on the 10 minutes to pandas. (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). With DataFrames, always try to take advantage of vectorization options rather than iterating

Comment: try not to iterate over a dataframe. the "best" method would depend on exactly what you want to do, so it'd be helpful if you could provide an example of a specific calculation you want to do

Comment: Also, watch out for using slices/chained assignment

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want wii games an easy way to do this is the following. Let's take a toy dataframe example:

```
# Dataframe 'games':

  console       title
0    Xbox        Halo
1     Wii  Smash Bros
```

To get all the rows with wii games, you can run

```
games[games["console"] == "Wii"]

# returns 
console       title
1     Wii  Smash Bros
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any follow up questions/want more detail